# Passing functions as arguments in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I'm trying to write a function that is gets two arrays and the name of another function as arguments.

e.g.

```
main.m:

    x=[0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0];
    y=[0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0];

    func2(x,y,'func2eq')

func 2.m :
    function t =func2(x, y, z, 'func')   //"unexpected matlab expression" error message here    
    t= func(x,y,z);

func2eq.m:  
    function z= func2eq(x,y)

    z= x + sin(pi * x)* exp(y);
```

Matlab tells gives me the above error message. I've never passed a function name as an argument before. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could also use function handles rather than strings, like so:

`main.m`:

```
...
func2(x, y, @func2eq); % The "@" operator creates a "function handle"
```

This simplifies `func2.m`:

```
function t = func2(x, y, fcnHandle)
    t = fcnHandle(x, y);
end
```

For more info, see the documentation on [function handles](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html)

Answer (score 10):

You could try in `func2.m`:

```
function t = func2(x, y, funcName)  % no quotes around funcName
    func = str2func(funcName)
    t = func(x, y)
end
```

Comment: At least in  v. 2015,  if you don't quote the funcName, MATLAB interpreter expects arguments to be supplied. were you thinking that funcName is a handle?