# Matlab - using a .m file as an input to a function

Tags: function, matlab, input

I am trying to create a matlab function which can accept any .m file and output tests run on it for example tic toc.

Basically I'd like something along the lines of:

function [time] = func (program.m)

tic
program.m();
time = toc;

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730029/passing-functions-as-arguments-in-matlab).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the XUnit test framework for MATLAB, it does this and more: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846-matlab-xunit-test-framework