# Passing function as arguments in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, interpolation, spline

I've just started to program and i've had some problems in passing function as arguments using MATLAB. I've to implement Lagrange algorithm for interpolation.

`C1` and `C2` are vectors that represent points to interpolate coordinates.

My main problem is that I don't know how to explain in my `f1` definition that `temp1` and `temp2` are not variables, but values determined on every iteration of a `for` loop (for `i` and `j`).

I think the code remaining part could be almost correct.

```
function [  ] = lagrange(C1, C2)

n  = length(C1);
f2 = inline('');
g  = inline('');

for i = 1:n

    temp0 = C2(i);
    temp1 = C1(i);

    for j = 1:n

        if (i~=j)
             temp2 = C1(j);
             temp3 = C2(j);

            f1 = inline('(x-temp2/(temp1-temp2)','x','temp1','temp2');
            f2 = f2.*f1
        end

        g = g+temp0*f2;   

    end

end

%plot g
end
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the inline objects? Why not compute `f1` and `f2` directly?

Comment: this doesnt help?-> [Passing functions as arguments in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730029/passing-functions-as-arguments-in-matlab?rq=1)