# Passing function name as argument in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, handle, function-handle

I know this question is already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730029/passing-functions-as-arguments-in-matlab) But I cannot make it work.

I have a simple function f1 :

```
function out = f1(x)
out = x^2 + 5;
end
```

and I want to have a "delegate" function that takes the function name as input. Below you can see my 2 trials :

```
% function out = delegate_function(the_input , func_handle)
% out = func2(the_input, func_handle);
% end

function out = delegate_function(the_input , funcname)
thefunc = str2func(funcname);
out = thefunc(the_input);
end
```

Both of them give the same error when I call this in the command window :

```
delegate_function(2 , f1); % I want ans = 9

Error using f1 (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the version above working, you have to pass the name of the function, which is

```
delegate_function(2 , `f1`);
```

I would strongly recommend to use a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/function-handles.html) instead:

```
function out = delegate_function(the_input , func_handle)
out = func_handle(the_input);
end
```

Then you have to call `delegate_function` using:

```
delegate_function(2 , @f1);
```

Comment: Yes! Your second answer is the one I'm looking for. Thanks :)